# Loop through all options in a selection and add the value to the option name

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I have a selection all with different values.
What I want to do is loop through each option if the value contains the text "pa_course-date" and add it to the option name "Course Date"

So it reads "Course Date - pa_course-date-aromatherapy" and so on

I would not where to start with this one. If a javascript expert can take a look I will be very happy.

```
<option value="pa_course-date-aromatherapy">Course Date</option>
<option value="pa_course-date-basic-colouring">Course Date</option>
<option value="pa_course-date-body-wraps">Course Date</option>
<option value="pa_course-date-brow-tinting">Course Date</option>
<option value="pa_course-date-cold-fusion">Course Date</option>
```

Comment: `for (value of class.values) let string = "Course Date" + value`

Comment: I propose an edit in order to explain in the body of the question what is the result you expect.

Comment: Hi, So instead of each drop down just saying Course Date, I want it to display Course Date - value i.e "pa_course-date-aromatherapy" Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```js
const options = document.querySelectorAll('.attribute_taxonomy option');

options.forEach(o => {
  const currentValue = o.getAttribute('value');
  o.innerHTML = `Course Date - ${currentValue}`;
});
```

```html
<select name="attribute_taxonomy" class="attribute_taxonomy">

<option value="pa_course-date-aromatherapy">Course Date</option>
<option value="pa_course-date-basic-colouring">Course Date</option>
<option value="pa_course-date-body-wraps">Course Date</option>
<option value="pa_course-date-brow-tinting">Course Date</option>
<option value="pa_course-date-cold-fusion">Course Date</option>     

</select>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your input. I may have other selection boxes on that page also called attribute_taxonomy would it be possible to search out if any option value contains "pa_course-date" then append the value ?

Comment: Do you wanna append only the options that contain the words `pa_course-date` in the value?

Answer (score 1):

Try this code inside a select,

```
return valueList.map(v => {
    if(v === "pa_course-date") {
        return <option value={"Course Date" + v}>{"Course Date" + v}</option>
    }
})
```

Answer (score -1):

This should work fine

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#select>option").each(function(){
   $(this).text(this.text + ' - ' + this.value)
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="select">
  <option value="pa_course-date-aromatherapy">Course Date</option>
  <option value="pa_course-date-basic-colouring">Course Date</option>
  <option value="pa_course-date-body-wraps">Course Date</option>
  <option value="pa_course-date-brow-tinting">Course Date</option>
  <option value="pa_course-date-cold-fusion">Course Date</option>     
</select>
```

Comment: I wonder why my response get downvoted am I missing anything?